# Conditional probability with n correlated random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

I encounter this problem in one of my research projects in economic/applied statistics decision making.

Suppose there is a random variable $\omega \in \{1,0\}$ with $\Pr (\omega
=1)=q\in (0,1).$ There are $n$ agents each of whom receives a noisy signal $%
s_{i}\in \{1,0\}$ about $\omega $. The precision of each signal is $\Pr
(s_{i}=\omega |\omega )=\gamma >\frac{1}{2}$. The pairwise conditional
correlation between any two signals is $Corr(s_{i}$,$s_{j}|\omega )=\rho \in
\lbrack 0,1]$.

My questions are how do I calculate (i)
\begin{equation*}
\Pr (s_{1}=1,s_{2}=1,...s_{i-1}=1,s_{i+1}=1,...s_{n}=1|s_{i}=0,\omega =1),
\end{equation*}
i.e., what is the probability that $n-1$ other agents receive $s=1$
conditional on the fact that agent $i$ receives $s_{i}=0$ and the state is $%
\omega =1?$

(ii) More generally, what is the probability that $n_{1}$ agents receive $s=1
$ and $n_{2}$ agents receive $s=0$ conditional on the fact that $n_{3}$
agents receive $s=1$ and $n_{4}$ agents receive $s=0$ and the state is $%
\omega =1$ such that $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}=n?$

I can solve the problem with $n=2$, that is, for example, $Pr(s_{2}=1|s_{1}=0,w=1)=\gamma(1-\rho)$, but find difficulty from $n=3$ and more. I have also consulted the document "Multivariate Bernoulli Distribution" by Dai et al. However, not much luck yet.

I will appreciate some help.

Comment: What have you yourself tried, prior to posting here to request others answer your questions for you?  Where did you encounter this question? Under what topic of study?

Comment: I can solve the problem for n=2, that is, Pr(s2=1|s1=0,w=1), but find difficulty from n=3 and more. I have also consulted the document "Multivariate Bernoulli Distribution" by Dai et al. However, not much luck yet. I encounter this problem in one of my research projects in economic decision making.

Comment: I don't think you have enough information for $n\gt2$. For instance, for $n=3$ you have $3$ correlations and $3$ means (all conditional on $\omega$), which makes $3+3=6$ conditions in all, but you have $8-1=7$ degrees of freedom in the probabilities for the $8$ possible results, so one degree of freedom is left; I haven't checked this, but it seems likely that this remaining degree of freedom could be used to change the desired conditional probability without violating any of the conditions.

Comment: Hi Joriki, what information do you think would be necessary to solve the problem for n=3, for example?

Comment: Hi Joriki, we also have the information about 3 variances.

Comment: No help? Surprised.